# Best clear finish for German beech to avoid blotching?

Tags: finishing

We have used beech in our bathroom and used WoodDoc Antique Wax to protect it. Unfortunately, although it looked beautiful, it did nothing to protect the surface from water splashes. We stripped the wax finish using white spirits as recommended and sanded the surface down.
After some research and feedback from a company that supplies Osmo oil based finishes, we ordered the Osmo 4006 wood protector and the 1101 extra thin finish coat which is supposed to protect against water damage.

We were advised to do a test run, which we did on a pair of beech side tables which had also previously been treated with antique wax. After removing the wax and sanding the surface, we applied the Osmo wood protector. The result was terrible blotching which had not been apparent after waxing. Applying the finish coat did nothing to remedy the mottled blotchy appearance.

Since then, further research has revealed that German beech is also prone to blotching with the use of tung oil.

What do finish do you recommend that will allow us to maintain the beauty of the natural wood and provide a waterproof barrier against water splashes? Similar question did not deal with this specific problem.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange. Beech in general isn't noted for being a blotch-prone wood. This is European beech, which should all be *Fagus sylvatica* across all of Europe. So could you post some pictures of the test side tables? It's possible you either incompletely stripped the wax (this is fairly common as the technique is often not described properly, so the user skimps on paper towels and/or solvent.... for example, did you do it 3 times?). It's also possible you didn't sand enough (didn't start coarse enough, or didn't sand long enough, or both). Or a combination of these two things.

Comment: Re. waterproofing in general, if you want a proper waterproof barrier then you really need to use varnish or lacquer. Notwithstanding maker claims to the contrary, thin-film (or no-film), close-to-the-wood finishes can't hope to compete with a film finish, simply because there's so little of the product present. Now that said, I have seen comparison tests made between some of the Osmo finishes and competitor products, where one or more of the competitors did *a lot* better than the Osmo, despite being the same sort of finish (according to the label at least).